# Replacing multiple substrings in C#

Tags: c#, strings, .net, tree

There is a [`String.Replace` method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-6.0) in C# and it is 1-1 mapping replacing operation, i.e. single Unicode character / string source replaced with another single Unicode character / string target. Considering the case of 1-to-multiple replacing task, for example, replacing "1" in "123" with  "A", "B" and "C" separately (result: "A23", "B23" and "C23"), I am attempting to propose a `Generate` method to deal with this kind of task.

**Replacing Rule Representation**

Tree structure is used for representing 1-to-multiple replacing rule. Following the mentioned example, the tree structure is like:

```
(root)-- "1" ---- "A"
            |---- "B"
            |---- "C"
```

The nodes in level 2 are the old strings to be replaced and the the nodes in level 3 are the new strings to replace all occurrences of its parent node.

**The experimental implementation**

- `Generate` method implementation:

  ```
  public static class StringsBatchReplacingTool
  {
    public static List<string> Generate(string inputString, NTree<string> replacingRules)
    {
      List<string> results = new List<string>();
      results.Add(inputString);
      foreach (var Node in replacingRules.Nodes)      //    First layer
      {
        if (!inputString.Contains(Node.Data))
        {
          continue;
        }
        results = BatchReplace(results, Node);
      }
      return results;
    }

    private static List<string> BatchReplace(List<string> input, NTree<string> replacingRules)
    {
      List<string> results = new List<string>();
      foreach (var replaceTarget in replacingRules.Nodes)
      {
        foreach (var inputItem in input)
        {
          results.Add(inputItem.Replace(replacingRules.Data, replaceTarget.Data));
        }
      }
      return results;
    }
  }
  ```
- The used `NTree` class implementation:

  ```
  //  Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012855

  public delegate void TreeVisitor<T>(T nodeData);

  public class NTree<T>
  {
    public T Data;
    public LinkedList<NTree<T>> Nodes;

    public NTree()
    {
      Nodes = new LinkedList<NTree<T>>();
    }

    public NTree(T data)
    {
      this.Data = data;
      Nodes = new LinkedList<NTree<T>>();
    }

    public void AddChild(T data)
    {
      Nodes.AddFirst(new NTree<T>(data));
    }

    public void AddChild(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        foreach (var eachData in data)
        {
          AddChild(eachData);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the specific child with the given index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="i">Index of child, start from 0</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public NTree<T> GetChild(int i)
    {
      i++;
      foreach (NTree<T> n in Nodes)
        if (--i == 0)
          return n;
      return null;
    }

    public void Traverse(NTree<T> node, TreeVisitor<T> visitor)
    {
      visitor(node.Data);
      foreach (NTree<T> kid in node.Nodes)
        Traverse(kid, visitor);
    }
  ```

**Test Cases**

Following the mentioned example, the code for testing:

```
NTree<string> nTree = new NTree<string>();
nTree.AddChild("1");
nTree.GetChild(0).AddChild("C");
nTree.GetChild(0).AddChild("B");
nTree.GetChild(0).AddChild("A");

var testResults = StringsBatchReplacingTool.Generate("123", nTree);
foreach (var eachResult in testResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(eachResult);
}
```

The output of above code:

```
A23
B23
C23
```

Another more complex test case: for input string "123", replacing "1" with  "A", "B" and "C" and replacing "2" with  "D", "E" and "F" separately.

```
NTree<string> nTree = new NTree<string>();
nTree.AddChild("1");
nTree.GetChild(0).AddChild("C");
nTree.GetChild(0).AddChild("B");
nTree.GetChild(0).AddChild("A");
nTree.AddChild("2");
nTree.GetChild(0).AddChild("F");
nTree.GetChild(0).AddChild("E");
nTree.GetChild(0).AddChild("D");

var testResults = StringsBatchReplacingTool.Generate("123", nTree);
foreach (var eachResult in testResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(eachResult);
}
```

The output of above code:

```
AD3
AE3
AF3
BD3
BE3
BF3
CD3
CE3
CF3
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This triple `foreach` inside the `Generate` method seems really suspicious. Are you sure you need all of them? As I can see you have a recursive `Traverse` method which is unused. Do you use it in a different code piece which is not shared with us?